# ElastiCache High availability architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, high-availability, amazon-elasticache

Our SaaS product deployment uses a two mirror(serving / non serving) architecture where the two mirrors don't share anything (database / app services are all isolated between mirror in two different AZs) within each mirror is deployed with infrastructure/services in each AZ. This includes ec2 instances(mirror 1 would have ec2s from AWS AZ1 vs mirror two will have in AZ2 as an e.g.). We divert traffic automatically based on health assessment of the mirror and failover between mirrors.
I am leading an effort to add ElastiCache / Redis into the system. I have two options:

1. Uses HA clustered more where mirrors use a single HA cluster
2. Two separate mirror specific elastic clusters.

Any opinions on folks who are experienced with running in production ElastiCache in large scale on cost/ benefit on sharing / not sharing.?

Comment: It's "ElastiCache" There's only one `c`.  https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/

Comment: It sounds like you currently have a hot-standby failover architecture for disaster recovery. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to keep that architecture going as-is, by create two separate Redis ElastiCache clusters.

Comment: Yep you got it. Just wondering from a cost stand point and what it gives. Guess isolation from each cluster is a given. Thanks for the input.